# Prove that the inner product is the number of orbits of $G$ on $X \times Y$.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory

Let $X,Y$ be $G$-sets and $\mathbb{C}[X], \mathbb{C}[Y]$ the corresponding permutation representations.
Prove that the inner product is the number of orbits of $G$ on $X \times Y$.

Ive tried:

$$\begin{align}\langle \mathbb{C}[X], \mathbb{C}[Y] \rangle &= \frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g \in G}\chi_{\mathbb{C}[X]} \overline \chi_{\mathbb{C}[Y]} \\
&= \frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g \in G}\text{ number of fixed points of $g$ on $X$} \cdot  \text{ number of fixed points of $g$ on $Y$} \\
&= \frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{x \in X}\text{ number of $\{g \in G | gx=x \}$} \cdot  \sum_{y \in Y}\text{ number of $\{g \in G | gx=x \}$} \\
&= \frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{x \in X}stab(x) \cdot  \sum_{y \in Y}stab(y) \\
&= \frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{x \in X}\frac{|G|}{orbit(x)} \cdot  \sum_{y \in Y}\frac{|G|}{orbit(y)} \\
&= |G| \sum_{x \in X}\frac{1}{orbit(x)} \cdot  \sum_{y \in Y}\frac{1}{orbit(y)} \\
&= |G| \sum_{orbits,O}\sum_{x \in O}\frac{1}{orbit(x)} \cdot \sum_{orbits,O}\sum_{y \in O}\frac{1}{orbit(y)} \\
&= |G| \sum_{orbits,O}\sum_{x \in O}\frac{1}{orbit(x)} \cdot \sum_{orbits,O}\sum_{y \in O}\frac{1}{orbit(y)} \\
&= |G| \sum_{orbits,O}\sum_{x \in O}\frac{1}{orbit(x)} \cdot \sum_{orbits,O}\sum_{y \in O}\frac{1}{orbit(y)} \\
&= |G| \sum_{orbits,O}1 \cdot \sum_{orbits,O}1 \\
\end{align}$$

Now there shouldnt be a $|G|$ left. This implies a lack of understanding somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't it simply because 
$$
\text{ number of fixed points of $g$ on $X$} \cdot  \text{ number of fixed points of $g$ on $Y$}=\text{ number of fixed points of $g$ on $X \times Y$}
$$
and then you use the result that [the average of these numbers over $G$ is the number of orbits of $G$ on $X \times Y$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside%27s_lemma):
$$
\text{number of orbits of $G$ over $X \times Y$} = \frac{1}{\lvert G \rvert}\sum_{g\in G}\text{number of fixed points of $g$ on $X \times Y$}.
$$

Comment: This is very close to what I have done so there must be an erroneous step though in my attempted solution